# How can I remove (or replace with NA) data over a given value from a specific column?

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with dN/dS ratios (biology, not important to the question) and have ended up with some artifacts in my data (anything greater than 3 in a particular column is likely unreliable or an error) and I need to remove those artifacts before I make a histogram.

I am working with an imported xlxs file. One column in it contains the applicable data.

I have tried the following code

```
library(data.table)

outlierReplace = function(dataframe, cols, rows, newValue = NA) {  
    if (any(rows)) {  
        set(dataframe, rows, cols, newValue)  
    }  
}  

outlierReplace(X23k_Genome_dNdS_For_R, 
               `manual dN/dS`, 
               which(X23k_Genome_dNdS_For_R$`manual dN/dS` > 3), 
               NA)
```

This returned error codes (as follows)

```
Error in set(dataframe, rows, cols, newValue) :   
  Can't assign to the same column twice in the same query (duplicates detected).  
In addition: Warning message:  
In set(dataframe, rows, cols, newValue) :  
  Coerced j from numeric to integer. Please pass integer for efficiency;   e.g., 2L rather than 2
```

To emphasize, I have 23k rows, 7 columns. I am trying to replace all values in the column "manual dN/dS" that are above 3 with NA's

You may need to install data.table to use the set() function

Sample data

```
dat = data.table("seq1"=c("CAA_0000006-RA", "CAA_0000007-RA"), 
                 "seq2"=c("CAB_00000010-RA", "CAB_00000011-RA"),
                 "dN/dS"=c(0.4689, 0.1001), "dN"=c(0.0074, 0.0021),
                 "dS"=c(0.0169,0.0206),
                 "manual dN/dS"=c(0.4379,0.1019),
                 "man. dN/dS w/Nas"=c(0.437869822,0.101941748))
```

Comment: Please consider posting both code and example data, to make it easier to understand the issue, and easier (less effort for folks who want to take a shot at answering) to provide possible solutions.

Comment: I added some more information, hope it can help.

Comment: Ok, two more questions. (1) What R package is `set()` coming from? (2) Can you make a very small example dataset that we can use to run your function and reproduce the same error message? It probably should have the same column and row names that you are referring to in the function call. Something along the lines of `dat = data.frame("Fruit Type"=c("apple", "banana"), "Fruit Color"=c("red", "yellow"), "Length_cm"=c(8,  20))`.

Comment: I added the required package (i believe) and the data sample.

Comment: Rather than trying to troubleshoot your function, I will offer a more simple proposed solution. ```dat[`manual dN/dS` > 0.4, `manual dN/dS`:=NA_real_]```. Going forward, I would highly recommend renaming your columns without spaces, slashes, plus symbol, etc.

Comment: Thank you, going to give this a shot - this data was handed to me by someone else in our lab; I will go ahead and correct those things though. Working to clean this

Comment: Your example data should also have at least one row that contains a value that shall be replaced by `NA`. Otherwise proposed solutions show no effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)    
setDT(dat)
dat[`manual dN/dS` > 3, `manual dN/dS` := NA]
```

Please note that your example data does **not** contain the column you mentioned in your question.

Please do also note that spaces and special characters like slashes in column names are bad practice since you always have to "quote" the names in your R code.

You can rename the column name eg. via `data.table::setnames(data, "old name", "new name")` (see help for this function)